# Distinct Column Selection using Spring JPA Specifications and Pagination gives InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to filter results from a table based on a bunch of query parameters I receive using Spring Data JPA Specifications. I need to get results of Distinct Column which is of type `UUID`. All the other query params I need to query by are of type `String`.

So the repository method I try is `findDistinctByTransactionId(Specficiation<T> spec, Pageable page)`

I expect the result to be of type `Page<UUID>`. But I get an exception. The error message is :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications@7c900524] did not match expected type [java.util.UUID (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications@7c900524] did not match expected type [java.util.UUID (n/a)]
```

So the problem here is the way to let the JPA know that the Distinct Column we are looking for is of type UUID.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to combine two distinct feature of Spring Data JPA: Specifications and Query Derivation. This does not work.

What you should do is create a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) of your method which constructs a query using the JPA Criteria API and then adds the predicate you pass in as an argument.